# Allocate ID in objectify datastore

Tags: objectify

I have a question about `ObjectifyFactory.allocateId()` in Objectify Datastore.

When you allocate an ID, will that ID now never be generated in automatically when putting an entity in Datastore? Is there a chance it could? How can we know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. `allocateId()` is equivalent to using autogenerated-on-save ids. There's no risk of collision.

However, keep in mind that ids are scoped to {kind, parent}.

Comment: If I delete an entity of a certain kind, does it's `id` become available for `allocateId()` for that kind? Does the `allocateId()` method do something like check the datastore if that Id is available (even if it was used before but not anymore)?

Comment: No, the id will not become available again. Allocated ids are similar to sequences in other databases (although they aren't necessarily sequential); they are tracked separately from the contents of the table.

Comment: Does allocateId() makes save request slow?

Comment: `allocateId()` is a call to the service tier so it incurs the cost of an RPC but it seems to be pretty cheap. If you are generating these in bulk you may want to use the `allocateIds()` (plural) method and buffer them.

Comment: Is the same true for when an Id is auto-generated when putting an entity with no id? My use case is, I have a `User` entity. I want to be able to delete `User` entities but I also want to ensure an entity with a previously used `Id` never gets put in the future because that `id` is used in other entities properties and would not be the correct association. Do you think I would run into that problem? There is a datastore method `reserveIds` I was considering using after putting an entity (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/projects/reserveIds).

Comment: How many of these ids are you generating per second? Unless it's in the thousands, this is premature optimization.